# Android option menu

Tags: java, android, android-optionsmenu

In my project i have activity with options menu. I override `onOptionsItemSelected` method and add my handlers to menu items (switch-case block). But in one handler i need access to another menu item, how i can do that? findViewById doesn't work

```
 @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.visit:
                    //how to access another MenuItem from here?
                    return true;
                }
...
```

Comment: How could you access a menu item while its not clicked yet? Remeber you are accessing it from onOptionsItemSelected(), which will be called only when the menu item is selected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When creating your menu items, you could put the `MenuItem` you want to check in an attribute (i.e. one of the `private` fields of your class). This way, when you go into your method, you'll be able toacces the other menu item.

Comment: Thanks, but may be android have native mechanism for access options menu? For example, something like Activity.getOptionsMenu :)

Comment: From what I can grab in the javadoc, doesn't think so. But I don't see what the problem is with using a private field for this, it's basic OOP.